# Qt object if created (newed) with 'this' needs to be deleted or automatically deleted?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I want to know whenever create any Qt object such as `QTimer` in heap with `this` keyword or parented with any other `Qt` objects, needs to be deleted or it will be deleted automatically by the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your object is parented to an object tree, it will be collected when the tree root object is destroyed. You can still delete it before that if you need to.

> QObjects organize themselves in object trees. When you create a
>   QObject with another object as parent, the object will automatically
>   add itself to the parent's children() list. The parent takes ownership
>   of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its
>   destructor.

Comment: Hmm, so if the object created like this 'QTimer t = new QTimer' and 'QTimer t = new QTimer(parent)' are the same? So if not the same, then the first one needs to be deleted? Am I right?

Comment: No, you have to provide a parent if you want to put the object in an object tree. You can also set parent later but it is easier to just pass it to the constructor.